# Splitting a file into multiple files based on 1st column value

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have seen solutions of splitting a file with respect to pattern matching and line matching but what I want is the following. 
The scenario is, let's say I have a file `file1`  -

```
A.B|100|20
A.B|101|20
A.X|101|30
A.X|1000|20
B.Y|1|1
```

Now I want to split this file into 3 different files just based on the first column where the 1st file would be all the lines containing `A.B` in the first column, the 2nd file should have all the lines with `A.X` and so on.

If the first column changes in  **any way**, there should be a new file created for those lines. Is there any way of doing it with `bash`  or `awk`?

Since there is no way of actually knowing before hand what the first column value is, I wasn't able to use any feature like `split` or `cut`. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F\| '{print>$1}' file1
```

This writes each line to a file named after the first column.

How it works:

- `-F\|` sets the field separator to `|`.
- `print>$1` prints the current line to a file whose name is the first field.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thank you, will accept in 2 minutes.

Comment: (what surprises me about this, is that a second occurrence of the first field doesn't open a new instance of the file and write over the previous one.  that is, that ">>" isn't necessary.  ...been using shell for too long, i guess)

Comment: @Theophrastus That would be _shell_ behavior.  Awk is different.   With awk, `>` will overwrite a _previously_ existing file but, and this is where it differs from shell, while the awk command is running, `>` _appends_.

Comment: How do you do the same when you have space as a field separator?

Comment: @Techiee  `awk -F" " '{print>$1}' file1`

Comment: This might be too much to ask, but I really want to know, how can I write all these files into one sub-folder, instead of the current folder?

Comment: @user3768495  `awk -F\| '{print>"subfolder/"$1}' file1`

Comment: Tried a bunch of different ways to concatenate the `subfolder` with `$1` but without success. Thanks for providing the answer, @John1024!

Comment: How can we ignore the delimiter that is coming inside String column with double quotes ""? i.e A.B|"10|0"|20

Comment: Just stumbled across this for the second time. Already upvoted 4 years ago, and I am sad that I cannot once again (though I tried). Thank you @John1024!

Comment: @Scot I appreciate your comment.  It is nice to know that an answer has been helpful.