# Splitting file by 1st column: Too many open files

Tags: text-processing, awk, io

This is an extension of the question: [Splitting a file into multiple files based on 1st column value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297683/splitting-a-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-1st-column-value?newreg=f59b8e08741d4c93b7c57484f9d3b576). Since I just joined, I do not have enough rep points to add a comment to the above question. Therefore, I apologize for the duplication.

I am using the following command to split my file by the 1st column:

```
awk -F"\t" '{print>"subfolder/"$1}' inputfile
```

However, I am getting a `awk: cannot open for output (Too many open files)`.

Then I changed my command to the following

`awk -F"\t" '{print>"subfolder/"$1}{close("subfolder/"$1)}' inputfile`.

However, closing the file is producing 0 bytes output files.

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you just use one command block (i. e. `'{print>"subfolder/"$1; close("subfolder/"$1)}'`)?

Comment: @DopeGhoti, Thank you. That seems to have worked. Also, how do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Using `print >filename` in `awk` will open the file and truncate its length down to zero, if it existed.  `awk` would then *keep the file open* until the end of the program.  If you do this for many files, you would run into resource limitations, as you have noticed.

What you would need to do is to `close(filename)`.  In your case `close("subfolder/"$1)`.  You would need to do this while `$1` still has the correct value.

This means, however, that then *next* `print >` to that file would open the file and truncate its previous content.

To get around this, use `print >>` instead of `print >`.  This would open the file for *appending*.

The next issue would be that if you ran your `awk` program a second time, the results of the first run would just get appended to.  This means that you would have to organise for the output files to be removed or renamed before running the program again.

The complete script may look something like

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf subfolder   # remove old output files 
mkdir subfolder    # and recreate output directory

awk -F '\t' '{ fname = "subfolder/" $1; print >>fname; close(fname) }' inputfile
```

There's an ever so slight optimisation that you may benefit from if your data is sorted on the first column, and that is to not close the file until you actually need to:

```
awk -F '\t' '
    fname != "subfolder/" $1 {
        if (fname != "")
            close(fname)
        fname = "subfolder/" $1
    }
    { print >>fname }' inputfile
```

If the input is truly sorted on the 1st field, then you can change `print >>` to `print >` above.  Even if your data is not sorted, this (with `print >>`) would write multiple consecutive lines that happens to have the same 1st field to the same file without closing and re-opening the output file in-between (which may potentially be slow).

---

[As mosvy points out in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498001/splitting-file-by-1st-column-too-many-open-files/498007?noredirect=1#comment916606_498007), you may well want to ensure that the value used for the filename is *sane* before blindly writing to it.

You could do that by explicitly checking that the value contains only e.g. lower or upper case alphanumerical characters (and underscore):

```
awk -F '\t' '
    fname != "subfolder/" $1 {
        if (fname != "")
            close(fname)
        fname = "subfolder/" $1

        if (fname ~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/) {
            print "Bad filename: " fname >"/dev/stderr"
            exit(1)
        }
    }
    { print >>fname }' inputfile
```

He also suggests an alternative way of handling the redirection to the output file which would truncate the file when opening it for the first time, but would open it for appending any other time.  He does that by saving the filenames as keys in an associative hash:

```
    {
        if (names[fname]++)
            print >>fname
         else
            print >fname
    }
```

Comment: also creating files with names based on input data is **asking for it**; really. so: `awk '$1~/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/{ print "bad filename "$1 > "/dev/stderr"; next } { if(a[f="subdir/"$1]++) print >> f; else print > f; close(f) }'`

Comment: @mosvy You are absolutely correct.