# Extract lines into separate files named based on the string in each non-empty first column

Tags: awk, csv

I've got a csv `mappings.csv` shown below. I'd like to extract a block of records into separate files relating to each record that has a non-empty first field. The files are shown after `mappings.csv`.

```
$ cat mappings.csv
TEST1,,,a,a,a,a
,,,b,b,b,b
,,,c,c,c,c
TEST2,,,aa,aa,aa,aa
,,,bb,bb,bb,bb
,,,cc,cc,cc,cc
,,,dd,dd,dd,dd
TEST3,,,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa
,,,bbb,bbb,bbb,bbb
```

Output files based on `mappings.csv` is below:

```
$ cat TEST1.csv
TEST1,,,a,a,a,a
,,,b,b,b,b
,,,c,c,c,c
```

```
$ cat TEST2.csv
TEST2,,,aa,aa,aa,aa
,,,bb,bb,bb,bb
,,,cc,cc,cc,cc
,,,dd,dd,dd,dd
```

```
$ cat TEST3.csv
TEST3,,,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa
,,,bbb,bbb,bbb,bbb
```

I'm able to use awk to print lines that have a non-empty first field, but can't figure out how to expand and print subsequent records up to the next non-empty first field:

```
$ awk -F',' '$1' mappings.csv
TEST1,,,a,a,a,a
TEST2,,,aa,aa,aa,aa
TEST3,,,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa
```

The other aspect of this problem is separating out the results into separate files. One thing I could do is use the matching record numbers to print out lines between the two. Something kind of like this:

```
$ awk -F',' '$1 {print NR}' mappings.csv
1
4
8
```

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked + answered before - you can just do something like `awk -F, '$1 != "" {close(f); f = $1 ".csv"} {print > f}' mappings.csv`

Comment: @steeldriver Wow, this works great! What is going in the second action: `{print > f}`? In the first action, a nonempty first field matches, it closes the file and assigns the file name to `f`?.

Comment: OK this seems sufficiently different from previous questions - at any rate, I have added an answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although very similar question have been asked and answered before, e.g.

- [Extract data from a file and place in different files based on one column value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114061/extract-data-from-a-file-and-place-in-different-files-based-on-one-column-value)
- [Splitting a file into multiple files based on 1st column value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297683/splitting-a-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-1st-column-value)

I can't find an exact duplicate where the file names should be taken only from non-empty values of a specified column. So given:

```
$ cat mappings.csv 
TEST1,,,a,a,a,a
,,,b,b,b,b
,,,c,c,c,c
TEST2,,,aa,aa,aa,aa
,,,bb,bb,bb,bb
,,,cc,cc,cc,cc
,,,dd,dd,dd,dd
TEST3,,,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa
,,,bbb,bbb,bbb,bbb
```

then

```
awk -F, '$1 != "" {close(f); f = $1 ".csv"} {print > f}' mappings.csv
```

results in

```
$ head TEST*
==> TEST1.csv <==
TEST1,,,a,a,a,a
,,,b,b,b,b
,,,c,c,c,c

==> TEST2.csv <==
TEST2,,,aa,aa,aa,aa
,,,bb,bb,bb,bb
,,,cc,cc,cc,cc
,,,dd,dd,dd,dd

==> TEST3.csv <==
TEST3,,,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa
,,,bbb,bbb,bbb,bbb
```

The first action closes the file named `f` (if one is open), then constructs a new value for `f` by concatenating the (non-empty) value of the first field `$1` with suffix `.csv`. The second action prints records to a file whose name is the (current) value of variable `f`. *Note that it will error out if `f` is empty, which will be the case if there are any lines **before** the first non-empty value of `$1`*.

Some awk implementations may take care of closing files for you in which case you don't need the explicit `close(f)`.